# How to disable all management.health endpoints in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Which of the following properties is the correct one to disable any health endpoints (eg during unit/integration webtests):

```
management.health.defaults.enabled=false #for status of health.mail, health.db, etc
management.endpoint.health.enabled=false #for /health endpoint
```

Comment: spring boot 2.0.x uses `management.endpoint.health.enabled`, I *think* that `management.health.defaults.enabled` was before that... but either way, disable them both, who cares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also `management.endpoints.enabled-by-default` which probably suits better for my integration tests...